# How to optmize the method

Tags: java, recursion

I have been solving a problem in hackerrank. I am sure my solution is right but as the input matrix gets large the program terminates due to time out.

I have a method where i find a series given below. This method takes array index numbers and computes a number based on the method. Based on the number, i fill up my array with something. But the program terminates every time. It only works with for maximum n=2. I think this method should be optimized because it uses huge recursion for large n. Is there any suggestion what should i do ?

```
static int hacko(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else if(n==2)
        return 2;
    else if(n==3)
        return 3;
    else
     return hacko(n-1)+(2*hacko(n-2))+(3*hacko(n-3));

}
```

Comment: Recursion can be heavy for big `n`. Is recursion a requirement for your task?

Comment: No. It is not required. I want to use anything if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid unnecessary branches, which can be costly, like this:

```
static int hacko(int n) {

    if(n < 4)
        return n;
    else
        return hacko(n-1)+(2*hacko(n-2))+(3*hacko(n-3));

}
```

I assume `n > 0`, otherwise use `if(n > 0 && n < 4)`. However, you stated:

> It only works with for maximum n=2.

So the method you posted is most likely not the bottleneck, since `n=3` does not add any significant complexity to the code compared to `n=1` or `n=2`. Or what do you mean by this?

As recursion is not a requirement for you, you can do the following iterative approach:

```
static int hacko(int n) {

    // Shortcut for n=1, n=2 and n=3
    if (n < 4)
        return n;

    // Array to store the previous results
    int[] temp = new int[n];
    temp[0] = 1;
    temp[1] = 2;
    temp[2] = 3;

    // Iterative approach, more scalable, counts up
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
        temp[i] = 3 * temp[i - 3] + 2 * temp[i - 2] + temp[i - 1];
    }

    return temp[n - 1];

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That should reduce some complexity

Comment: Added an iterative solution, because you stated recursion is not required.

Comment: Omg! That's excellent. Thank you very much.You turned an ugly recursion to a simple iteration :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, for large values of n, it calculates hacko(n-1)+(2*hacko(n-2))+(3*hacko(n-3)) recursively. This can be time consuming and unnecessary.

You can optimize it by saving values of hackos(i) in an array and fetching the values of hacko(n-1)+(2*hacko(n-2))+(3*hacko(n-3)) from the array and not calculating it recursively everytime. U need to start the loop from i=1 to i=N

Ex:

```
int savedData[] = new int[N];
static int hacko(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else if(n==2)
        return 2;
    else if(n==3)
        return 3;
    else
     return savedData[n-1]+(2*savedData[n-2])+(3*savedData[n-3]);

}

for(int i=1;i<N;i++) {
savedData[i] = hacko(i);
}
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :). Yes i can certainly do this thing :)